# Copy/paste options color differ in android app

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm developing an android app, In login screen I'm getting dark copy option and in other activity I'm getting light copy option.

I want only dark options all over the my app.

[image]

[image]

My app theme in style.xml is:-

```
<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->

</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryColorDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accentColor</item>
    <item name="buttonStyle">@style/My.Button</item>
</style>
```

Comment: are you sure that both activities use your AppTheme? it should be in the manifest, either declared for <application> or for each <activity>

Comment: It declared only for application.

Comment: strange, but that should be enough

Comment: Thanks for your comments guys. I got the reason. I was using ToolBar theme in one activity.